# How to export data from getstream.io

Tags: export, getstream-io

I've some content (activities) available on [getstream](https://getstream.io/). 
Because of some reason, I have to refresh all the data. For this activity, I have to take the backup of current state.

Is there any way to export the activities available on getstream app?

I can't see any option on the getstream console/portal.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported at the moment, it's a work in progress but [support](https://getstream.io/support) gives a hand to export whatever is needed since it's your data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc *[Migrate existing data to a different region](https://support.getstream.io/hc/en-us/articles/4429177439895-Migrate-existing-data-to-a-different-region)*, up till now they have yet to implement this feature. However, you can probably use below non-programmatic method if your content is concentrated.

1. Navigate to your Activity Feeds application and then to the Explorer.
2. Open Developer Tools of your browser and navigate to "Network" tab.
3. Select down the "directories" till you reach your "activities" destination. Meanwhile, observe which network requests are fired. You can see such requests as `https://<region>.stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/feed/user/<user name>/?api_key=<key>&limit=<number>` whose response JSON contains the content you want to export. That's it!
4. Do this repeatedly till you export all your data.